# CSS Positioning Problem

Tags: wordpress, css, hyperlink, wordpress-theming

I've self-taught myself all of my web design skills and now I'm having a problem with CSS positioning. I'm trying to add a 'Play Video' icon in front of my Wordpress thumbnail image. I *think* I've got the classes set up correctly, but for some reason the 'Play' icon ends up in the top right of the nearest div. Can you guys help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I made it so that the Wordpress checks for certain custom fields before it assigns the span "videoimg" (which should display icon) so that only my video posts are assigned the icon. Here's my Index layout as well as my related CSS styles:

```
 <div class="featured-thumbnail">
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="nofollow">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail('index', array( 'title' => '' )); ?>
          <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, "_videoembed", true) || get_post_meta($post->ID, "_videoembed_manual", true)){ ?><?php echo('<span class="videoimg"></span>'); ?><?php } ?>
     </a>
 </div>
```

Here's my CSS for the elements:

```
.featured-thumbnail {
float: left;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: 5px;
z-index:2;
}

.featured-thumbnail img {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: opacity;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
z-index:1;
}

.featured-thumbnail img:hover{
opacity: .8;
-webkit-transition: opacity;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.featured-thumbnail .videoimg {
width:60px;
height:60px;
position:absolute;
z-index:6;
background: url(images/videoimg.png);
top:0;
right:0;
}
```

I know I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure out what it is. Here's how the 'Play' icon is displaying on the page (notice how it's on the top right instead of over the thumbnail image on the left-hand side):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5WiJI.png]

I would like to thank all helpers in advance, regardless if you can help me solve this mystery.

**UPDATE**

A number of friendly people have informed me that I need to use position:relative; for my .videoimg class styling. Does anyone know how I would be able to use an image taken out of a sprite as opposed to a standalone image (to help memory/page load times)? Here's what I have and a picture of the result:

```
   .featured-thumbnail .videoimg {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:6;
    background-image: url(images/sprites_social.png);
    background-position: 32px; 0px; 
    top:0;
    right:0;
    }
```

A quick pic of the sprite in fireworks:
[image]

..And the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's behaving exactly as it should - it's being absolutely positioned in reference to its closest non-statically positioned parent. Just add `position: relative;` to your `.featured-thumbnail` div:

```
.featured-thumbnail {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

#### Update:

As per request, for the second part of your problem - you need to use negative positions for sprites. I'd suggest using a tool like [SpriteCow](http://www.spritecow.com/) if you haven't ever done spriting on your own before.

#### Update 2:

Here is your Jsfiddle, updated to correctly show your sprite: [Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkNM5/1/)

Comment: Thank you so very much! I would love to help you in return! I don't know too much about coding, but I am a YouTube Partner and could give your channel a shout out (if you have one)

Comment: It's no problem; I'm just glad I got something working for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `position: relative;` to class "featured-thumbnail"

[update] I mean position: relative;

Comment: Did it hurt when you fell from Heaven? It worked, thanks broski!

Comment: Do you know if I'd be able to do the same thing with a sprite? I use them on the rest of my theme to decrease load time but I couldn't get it working earlier (probably because I was doing it wrong, but I'm still curious :P)

Comment: @Matt: You ought to be able to do the same thing with a sprite - just set the sprite container's width and height, use a negative `text-indent` and `overflow: hidden` on it, and adjust the background position as necessary.

Comment: @Nightfirecat is correct that it is still possible with sprite :) but I do not use the text-indent and overflow technique, I just specify the width and height of the container and change the position of the image in the "background" attribute for each container.

Comment: Can you help me, haha? My relative sprite location is url(images/sprites_social.png) and it's 60x60, but when I put in its location, X=32px Y=0, (background-position: 32px 0px;) it shows the first column of images. Here's a picture of the sprite in fireworks: http://i.imgur.com/oUabW.png

Comment: @Manny: I only suggest that for accessibility purposes - without it, there isn't any content to show if CSS was turned off, or for screen readers.

Comment: @Matt: You need to use negative positions. I'd suggest using a tool like [SpriteCow](http://www.spritecow.com/) if you haven't ever done spriting on your own before.

Comment: @Matt: try to use -32 for the value of x see if it solves the problem, I'm just guessing here without the actual sample, sorry

Comment: Manny & @Nightfirecat, can you please explain why you would use -x positions? the image is located on the underside of the top x-axis (touching top of png) and is located 32px in, then 60px right/down is where the image is located. I've updated my question for help in visualization.

Comment: @Matt: If you, for instance, put your background image on your `<body>` tag, a positive x position would move the image to start at that value: +x pixels from the left edge. In this case, we want to move the image to the left and up, which means moving it in the opposite direction. It starts to measure from the top-left corner, and out into the image from there for the positioning, so that's why we need negatives. Examples [here (positive values)](http://jsfiddle.net/YQ7cX/) and [here (negative values)](http://jsfiddle.net/YQ7cX/1/).

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. I've been playing around with it and I changed the top&right css classes to bottom&left. I've also been messing with the background-position but can't seem to find the play button, lol

Comment: @Nightfirecat, I've made another JSfiddle with my image location, could you help me out some more and figure out what locations I should use?
http://jsfiddle.net/tkNM5/

Comment: @Matt: Again, you'd simply use negative positions. See my answer for the updated fiddle, with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving your `.featured-thumbnail` class `position:relative;`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `position:absolute` to `position:relative` for `.featured-thumbnail .videoimg`.